# Regex Match terms in between delimiters

Tags: regex

I'd say I'm getting the hang at Regex but when it comes to extracting data, I'm lost. Here are the inputs I have to parse through:

Format:

`String(String,...String,Integer)`

Ex.

`Jeff(White,Male,24)`

`Mark Zuckerberg(Facebook,9)`

`Grocery(Eggs,Cheese,Pancake,Bread,Milk,Strawberry,0)`

I want to match the Strings and Integer, but not the commas or parenthesis.

This one is is a bit easy because the strings don't have symbols in them but the other day I needed to extract the word `cake` out of something like this:

`<Header><Body><font=Tahoma,15pt><b>cake <\b><\font>` and whenever I'd try, I'd match the entire statement, not just the cake word, because I'd do like:

`.*<b>[a-zA-Z]+<\b>.*`. So yeah... the whole concept of using Regex to extract bits of a string is foreign to me. How is it usually done in these two examples?

Comment: are you searching for Regex to extract `cake` out of `<Header><Body><font=Tahoma,15pt><b>cake <\b><\font>` ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm mainly looking for a solution to `String(String,...String,Integer)`. The other one is just out of curiosity since it's somewhat related.

Comment: no problem, i added answer for that case too. please review.

Comment: What language is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following .

```
(?<=<b>)\s*\cake\s*(?=<\\b>)
```

If you want to match word other than `cake`, try following.

```
(?<=<b>)\s*\w+\s*(?=<\\b>)
```

Regex to match string in first part of your  Question `(String(string, ... ,number))`

```
^\w+\((\w+,)+\d\)$
```

In the first part of your Question, if you like to match only words and number (Grocery,Eggs, ... ,0) in your string, try following

```
(?<=^|\(|\,)\w+
```

Comment: What if it could  be any word instead of `cake`

Comment: @Hatefiend no problem, use second option, namely `(?<=<b>)\s*\w+\s*(?=<\\b>)`

Comment: `^\w+\((\w+,)+\d\)$` Wow this is crazy. Let me try to see if I understand it. So... I searched `/w escape character` on Google and couldn't find anything. Does it mean word? I see at the end you havever `digit` followed by `)` literal character but wouldn't that match the character `)` and not ignore it?

Comment: Yes `\w` means word in `Regex`. For full detailed explanation, use [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iQ9dW8/1) . yes, `\)` will match, would you like it to be ignored ?

Comment: Yeah ideally I'd like the following... input : `This(Is,A,Good,Sentence,8)` to match the following highlighted text: `This`(`Is`,`A`,`Good`,`Sentence`,`8`)

Comment: @Hatefiend i updated my [answer](https://regex101.com/r/iQ9dW8/2). hope this works

Comment: Edited my response as I submitted it too early.

Comment: @Hatefiend As i see, given `Regex` [works for your input.](https://regex101.com/r/iQ9dW8/3)